# Graphics freeze unless I move mouse

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, freeze

I have a HP Elitebook 450 with Windows 7 installed. On all browsers, as well as desktop applications such as word, I have a problem that the graphics freeze untill I move my mouse. If I play a youtube video, the sound is transmitted without any delay, but the picture stops, untill i move the mouse. If there is constant mouse movement, the video will play without any freezing. The same happens when i type anything (like this question). This computer is more or less box fresh, can it be a hardware error? There is no difference if i use the trackpad or the USB plugged mouse. Interesting enough - scrolling a webpage doesn't take effect before I *move* the mouse.

Comment: sum simple checks , run a DirectX diagnosis C:\Windows\System32\dxdiag.exe.  Check either task manager or resource monitor (or both) for any odd or unusual activity , cpu , drive or even network.

Comment: @LPChip It has Windows 7 Enterprise and is a laptop issued by my employer in August.I can contact my IT department, but I hoped there was something I could do (missing drivers etc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably had the same problem with my HP Elitebook 840, Windows 7 Pro. The Video playback on the Youtube and on the other html5 video sites caused freezing graphics on whole screen. Only when mouse pointer was moving, screen was refreshing.
I had "Windows Classic" or "Windows 7 - basic" theme set. Finally **changing the theme to the aero based** helped me entirely. (I used classic theme for old applications. The old Java environment switched off the aero when started too.)

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the computer so I can check this, however I'll mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! This just fixed the same issue on my HP EliteBook 840 G2 with Windows 7 Enterprise, and restored my sanity. Would be interesting to know if there is a specific theme setting that causes this.

Comment: Thanks, this also fixed the issue for me on a Dell Latitude E7450